# UI Like Youtube in Android (Tablet)

Tags: user-interface, youtube, tablet, android

I've spent 2 hours looking for a solution. I need to make a design
like the Youtube UI (Tablet UI) where it shows a vertical scroll, but
in each row there are 4 videos (landscape view). I've tried to do
something similar, but i couldn't =(

Is there any place where i can get the source code of the youtube
application for Tablet? Or maybe some resource to solve this? :(

BTW, my try was designing UI with scrollView, LinearLayout and my_item.xml, i tried to inflate my_item.xml adding programmatically into the linearlayout (horizontal orientation), but it doesn't work in the way that i want. I need something like a linearlayout but with horizontal and vertical orientation at the same time (something like a div).

I was thinking to use a ListView and a custom adapter (with my_item.xml), but i'm not sure if this can be the best solution.

Thxs

Comment: You will need to give us more. Show us what you have so far. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: I've written a custom adapter with my_item.xml which has a horizontal linearlayout, everything is ok here, but i need to show more elements in a landscape view than in a portrait view, like youtube.
http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/8180/sc201112150833421.jpg

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally i solve my problem.

It works with a linearLayout(vertical) and adding linearlayout(horizontal) for each row. And obviously managing my scrollview.

BTW, i still think android should have a layout like a "div".

Thxs all

Answer (score 0):

You should create seperate resources for each layout.

For example if the user is in Portrait mode you would have the correct layout in.

```
layout-port: layout for portrait orientation

layout-land: layout for landscape orientation
```

Read more on providing alternative resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Also i would recommend to read more on [Handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

This will help you with recognizing when the user changes orientation. You could actually use this guide and when the user flips the devices orientation you could then change the layout. Keep in mind hard coding this can be dangerous though. I would recommend using the layout folders.

Good luck!

Comment: I know about how to manage alternative resources, but that's not my core problem. In my Custom Adapter i consider a list of objects each with 4 images (landscape view), but in my portrait view this object should have just 3 images. Also, i like the "loading more videos" of youtube UI

Comment: In few words i need a guide or clue to build an adapter for this listview (even i don't know if Listview is the right control for this)